# insert element in a list after every 2 element

Tags: python, list, insert

I have this code:

```
l = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0]

def add(l, n):
    lret = l.copy()
    i = n
    while i <= len(lret):
      lret.insert(i, 0.0)
      i += (n+1)
    return lret

lret = add(l,2)

print(lret)
```

Is a way to make the `add()` function a one-line function?

Comment: What if there are only 5 elements in `l`. Do you want `[1.0, 2.0, 0.0, 3.0, 4.0, 0.0, 5.0, 0.0]` or `[1.0, 2.0, 0.0, 3.0, 4.0, 0.0, 5.0]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `zip()` to build tuples that contain `n` elements from the original list with an added element, and then use `chain.from_iterable()` to flatten those tuples into the final list:

```py
from itertools import repeat, chain
def add(lst, n):
    return list(chain.from_iterable(zip(*(lst[s::n] for s in range(n)), repeat(0.0))))
```

This outputs:

```py
[1.0, 2.0, 0.0, 3.0, 4.0, 0.0, 5.0, 6.0, 0.0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution if you want the whole block in one line:

```
return [x for y in (l[i:i + n] + [0.0] * (i < len(l) - n + 2) for
                   i in xrange(0, len(l), n)) for x in y]
```

Gives the same output

> [1.0, 2.0, 0.0, 3.0, 4.0, 0.0, 5.0, 6.0, 0.0]

Answer (score 0):

Found another way to do it:

```py
def add(l,n=2):
    return [item for sublist in [(e,) if i % n == 0 or i == 0 else (e, 0.0) for i, e in enumerate(l)] for item in sublist]
```

> [1.0, 2.0, 0.0, 3.0, 4.0, 0.0, 5.0, 6.0, 0.0]